# moment.js time difference showing wrong result

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I need to know about some things about moment.js

I need to get difference in time
here my js code
Case 1:-

```
moment("Fri, 09 Mar 2018 09:16:00").from("Fri, 09 Mar 2018 10:00:00")
```

result :-  **"44 minutes ago"** ok right

Case 2:-

```
moment("Fri, 09 Mar 2018 09:15:00").from("Fri, 09 Mar 2018 10:00:00")
```

result :- **"an hour ago"** // i think it should show **"45 min ago"** message

I need most accurate time difference in case 2

there is any way to solve my problem

Comment: `moment().from()` is designed to show a friendly time and will probably suffice for most uses. If you want it exact then take a look at `moment().diff()` [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) however it won't be nicely formatted

Comment: It's working as intended. _"The breakdown of which string is displayed for each length of time is outlined in this table"_: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: Also you can change these thresholds -> eg.  `moment.relativeTimeThreshold("m", "49")`  would make it so that it goes to hours after 49 mins, instead of 45.  You can change to suite.

Comment: ok using moment.relativeTimeThreshold("m" , "60") is working 
but for date what i should use  moment.relativeTimeThreshold('d', 30)
but day vary on 29 , 30 , 31 in diffrent month ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the moment.js documentation (particularly [this page](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)) it is working as intended. For times between 45 and 89 minutes, it will display "an hour ago"

[image: Moment display table]

What you may need to consider using is using [Difference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) in moment.js

> To get the difference in minutes, use moment#diff like you would use moment#from.

Edit:

To use difference in the same way:

```
moment("Fri, 09 Mar 2018 09:15:00").diff("Fri, 09 Mar 2018 10:00:00", 'minutes');
```

Gives "-45". You may need to add your own function to turn that into something more useful, or if you know it will always be negative / "x minutes ago" use [Math.abs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp) to ensure a positive number

```
Math.abs(moment("Fri, 09 Mar 2018 09:15:00").diff("Fri, 09 Mar 2018 10:00:00", 'minutes'));
```

Comment: if I use moment diff method is will automatically show result like 44 minutes ago , 1 hour ago type some things

Comment: Have updated answer to include sample use of difference function to return a minute value

Comment: ok thanks and what about moment.relativeTimeThreshold("m" , "60")

Comment: I am using moment first time so do not know much more about it

if I use moment.relativeTimeThreshold("m" , "60") 
it will be good